# How to make thread safe string and int updates from background thread?

Tags: swift, swiftui

How should thread safe string and int updates be made from a background thread? Is this code thread safe? Thank you

```swift
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct MyView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var manager: DataManager
    @State private var itemsDoneInBackground = 0
    @State private var messageFromBackground = ""

    var body: some View {
      Text(messageFromBackground)
      Text("\(itemsDoneInBackground)")
    }

    func doBackgroundWork() {
        let backgroundContext = manager.backgroundContext()

        backgroundContext.perform {
            var itemsDone = 0
            var message = ""

            defer {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.itemsDoneInBackground = itemsDone
                    self.messageFromBackground = message
                }
            }
            
            for _ in 1...100 {
                itemsDone += 1
                messageFromBackground = "\(itemsDone) done"
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.itemsDoneInBackground = itemsDone
                }
            }

            message = "all done"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use async/await via SwiftUI's `.task` modifier and await a func declared outside of the main actor.

You need to remove `DispatchQueue.main.async` because that requires a reference type and SwiftUI `View` structs are value types that have no lifetime.

```
...
    .task { // runs on appear, cancelled on disappear, can be cancelled/restarted with task(id:) and id param changing.
        do {
            itemsDoneInBackground = await doBackgroundWork()
        }
        catch { 
            // exceptions when cancelled
        }
    }
} // var body

// Alternatively to nonisolated you can put this func in a non-@MainActor class or struct to also ensure a background thread.
nonisolated func doBackgroundWork() async throws -> [Item] {
        // will be background thread
        try Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1)) // if you want to simulate a delay
        return ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, can you elaborate on that?

Comment: I just read a post where GCD and the new concurrency are incompatible. Without further detail, it sounds like you are suggesting they be mixed.

Comment: @VictorEngel Very interesting! Would you be able to link to the post?

Comment: @VictorEngel I clarified the GCD code needs to be removed

Comment: @JohnCashew added an example

Comment: Sorry, I lost it. I've not used the new concurrency in Swift myself. I recall seeing a WWDC video introducing await, but that is all.

Comment: Thank you @malhal 1) how can i use this with perform on a core data background context, 2) how can i update State during execution of the background work?

Comment: 1 yes setting state is thread safe. 2 just set it like I did.